# Passport behind proxy doesn't persist session

Tags: javascript, express, nginx, passport.js, saml

## Situation

I have a frontend written in React, and an Express backend server handling SAML authentication process (Azure AD). This backend is accessible through the nginx server that serves the react application: it **proxy passes** all requests that are prefixed with `/api` to the backend. This way the backend is not known by the client, only by nginx.

[Schema of the architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGVNH.png)

The problem is that **Passport doesn't seem to work with this setup**. Here is how things are taking place:

1. The client clicks on the authentication button, and React requests the route `/api/login`.
2. NGINX proxy passes this request to my backend, where passport takes over.
3. The client logs successfully through the IDP form, and Passport correctly handles the callback function (I parse the profile received from the IDP, I recieve the user in the backend).
4. The backend redirects the client to the `/home` route, but the request session is not saved or never seems to be forwarded to the client, resulting in an authenticated client.

## Code

Here is the Passport initialization in `app.js`:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: 'none',
      domain: `https://${process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN}`
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'TOI_MEME_TU_LE_C'
  })
)
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

Here is my callback route in Express:

```
router.post('/saml/acs', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('saml', (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      let error = 'generic'
      if (err.message.includes('RequestDenied')) {
        error = 'request_denied'
      } else if (err.message.includes('unspecified')) {
        error = 'unspecified'
      }

      return res.redirect(`https://${process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN}/login?error=${error}`)
    }

    console.log(`${user.firstname} ${user.lastname} (${user.employeeId ?? '-> no employeeId <-'}) is connected.`)

    req.login(user, error => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Erreur lors du login.', error)
        return next(error)
      }

      console.log('Login successful, is authenticated?: ' + req.isAuthenticated())

      return res.redirect(`https://${process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN}`)
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

Note that both the logs are correctly displayed ! The second show that `req.isAuthenticated()` is valid and returns true.

Here is where the client, while having connected successfully, is still not authenticated for the backend (this is a classic `/me` route):

```
router.get('/me', (req, res) => {
  // it never goes past here, as neither the metho nor the user object exist in the request
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.status(401).send({ error: "Not connected." })
  }

  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: "No user on the request." })
  }

  res.status(200).json(req.user)
})
```

I tried removing my custom error handling in the Passport callback, but without any effect.
I tried changing cookies settings, no effect.

Why is Passport not correctly detecting authentication ?